# zf2, Form collections not creating correct input name in zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am trying create , html collection for colors input field .. which will dynamically added using javascript

My `ColorFieldset` code is

```
namespace Dashboard\Form;

use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;

class ColorFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct()
    {

        parent::__construct('color');

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'hash',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Color'
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'required' => 'required',
                'class'   => 'input-mini'
            )
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     \*/
    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        return array(
            'hash' => array(
                'required' => true,
            )
        );
    }
}
```

and added it into form

```
$this->add(array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
    'name' => 'colors',
    'options' => array(
        'count' => 2 ,
        'should_create_template' => true,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'target_element' => array(
            'type' => 'Dashboard\Form\ColorFieldset'
        )
    )
));
```

and in my view file .. `colors.phtml`

```
<div id="colors_container" class="">
     <?php  echo $this->formCollection( $form->get('colors')); ?>
</div>
```

it printing output like

```
<div class="" id="colors_container">

   <label><span>Color</span><input type="text" value="" class="input-mini" required="required" name="hash"></label>

   <label><span>Color</span><input type="text" value="" class="input-mini" required="required" name="hash"></label>

   <span data-template='<label><span>Color</span><input name="hash" required="required" class="input-mini" type="text" value=""></label>'></span>

</div>
```

It supposed to print like .. which explained in [zf2 manual 2.0](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html#adding-new-elements-dynamically)

```
<div class="" id="colors_container">

   <label><span>Color</span><input type="text" value="" class="input-mini" required="required" name="colors[0][hash]"></label>

   <label><span>Color</span><input type="text" value="" class="input-mini" required="required" name="colors[1][hash]"></label>

   <span data-template='<label><span>Color</span><input name="colors[__index__][hash]" required="required" class="input-mini" type="text" value=""></label>'></span>

</div>
```

I expected html input name as `colors[__index__][hash]` . But it printing name as `<input type="text" value="" class="input-mini" required="required" name="hash">` .

In above case .I will only get one color name in post `$_POST['hash']` .

why zf2 not print `<input type="text" value="" class="input-mini" required="required" name="colors[0][hash]">` ? Please advice what is wrong in my code .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ohh finally found answer by myself . I have to call

```
$form->prepare();
```

before rendering anything in the view . now it works

Comment: I spent so much time on this before finding your answer. Wish I had looked sooner. Thanks!

Comment: damm, lost day for this, and then find this answer. and is  upvoted before by me. lol .

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm. This code worked for me:

```
// prepare form is needed to properly display Collection fields
$form->prepare();

echo $this->form()->openTag($form);

// echo other normal form fields

echo $this->formCollection($form->get('colors'));

echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```